# R studioで日本語の文字化けが直りません。UTF8にして、par(family= "HiraKakuProN-W3")実行しても

Tags: r, rstudio

現状、MacbookでR studio Version 1.3.1056を使用しています。

Rを利用してプロットする際に日本語の文字化けが多発します。
csvファイルをUTF8にして、par(family= "HiraKakuProN-W3")を実行しても改善しません。

インターネット上の改善案はどれも同じで教授に聞いても「英語に直すしかない」と言われており、少し手詰まりなのでご教授頂けると幸いです。
例えばコレスポンデンス分析をしようと思い、バイプロットを表示させようとすると以下の画像のようになります。
[image: 日本語が文字化けしている例-バイプロット(CA関数)使用時]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データはそもそも正しく読み込まれている事を前提と考えて良いでしょうか？
(RStudio上では正しく表示されている？)

・もし日本語表示がそもそもおかしかったらRのターミナルから

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ja_JP.UTF-8")
```

を実行してみて下さい。

・device出力の際、OSによってかなりの挙動の差異があります。
　「PDFでダメならPNG形式で試す」を行うと問題の切り分けが出来ます。
　.png で出力できて .pdfでダメ、またはその逆などがあれば
　pdfラスタライザをcairo_pdfに変更するなどの対応が出来ると思います。
　(MacではX11の追加インストールが必要との事です。参考: https://ill-identified.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/10/03/200618#macux7279ux6709ux306eux5236ux7d04)

上記を踏まえまして、個人的に最も推奨したいのは
「dockerコンテナ化した環境でRStudioをつかう事」です。

また、RStudioはどのOS上でも内部はWebアプリとして動作していますので、
dockerコンテナとしての相性が素晴らしく良いです。

docker for mac をインストールして、
ターミナルから

```
docker run -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/tidyverse
open http://localhost:8787/
```

と2行打つだけで、ほぼ完璧な環境でビルドされたRStudioが起動します。
フォントを指定するだけで、日本語だけで無くほぼ全世界の言語が扱える事を確認済みです。

MacもWindowsほどではないですが、ローカルに手動で環境をビルドして再現性を保つのは
かなり骨の折れる作業です。
コンテナ化すれば Mac/Linux/Win 全てのホストOS上で全く同じ環境を再現出来ます。

ホントに5分で済むので、
もしMacの環境いじりに5分以上かかりそうでしたら一度試すのも悪くないかと存じます。

Comment: ご丁寧にコメントありがとうございます
r studio serverを使ったのですが、それでも文字化けが直らず、デスクトップ版で使用していたファイルにアクセスできませんでした。なので、docker fileをつくって解決しようとしたのですが、そもそも docker上でbuild できず今頓挫しています、、

Comment: rocker/tidyverseをお使いですね。
まずコンテナのdebianにフォントをインストールするのをお試し下さい。<br>

起動コマンドを変更して `sudo` を有効にします： 
`docker run  -e ROOT=TRUE -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/tidyverse`

起動したら、Rstudio下部の Terminal から下記を入力します：

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install fonts-noto-cjk`

最後に、Rから
ggplotなどの前に、 `par(family="Noto Sans")` を付けて試してみて下さい

Comment: 「日本語化 rocker プロジェクト」を有志の方が作っておられました。
https://hub.docker.com/u/rockerjp/
https://qiita.com/kazutan/items/1af4d0c4defb4de4b7fb

`docker run -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rockerjp/tidyverse`
でしたら特に設定無く日本語表示がデフォルトになるようです

Comment: デスクトップのファイルのマウントは、 -v オプションを使います。

Comment: `docker run -v ~/Desktop:/home/rstudio/host_desktop -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rockerjp/tidyverse`

Comment: これで、デスクトップがFileペインから見えるようにマウントされます。

Comment: ビルド出来ず、はどういう状態だろう？
上記のワンライナーはpullのみでローカルビルドは発生しませんので一度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: noto-sans はアラビア文字やアフリカ言語など、実に800を超える言語に一つのフォントファミリー指定で対応できる素晴らしい書体です。フォント関係のトラブルシュートの際はまず試してみると切り分けに役に立ちます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！返信できておらず申し訳ありません。taiyodayoさんの手順通りにやってみたいと思います！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

[MacOSのR/RStudioでplot関数で作図する際に、日本語の文字化けを治す方法](https://qiita.com/purple_jp/items/6626ec1ea4e34c7d45b1) の記事に、「FontBook.appにてインストールされているフォントであれば、par(family= "HiraKakuProN-W3")のように記述」と書かれています。

FontBook.appでインストール済みのフォントを確認されては如何でしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます泣泣
一応、fontbook の中にはインストールしているのですが、それでも機能しないです、、、
fontbookに入っている他の日本語のフォントを利用しても結局文字化けが続くので他に原因があるのかなあって今も調べています、、

Answer (score 1):

Mac版 RStudioで ggplot2 を使う場合ですが

```
theme_set(theme_grey(base_family = "HiraKakuProN-W6"))
```

をggplot2()コール前に実行すると日本語で出ませんか？